# how to set gem dependencies without having to declare them on the Gemfile that uses it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm building a gem locally, suppose it name is "MyGem".

Now suppose that MyGem depends on other already built gem, for example "cancan".

So, i've added in my mygem.gemspec the line:

```
add_runtime_dependency("cancan")
```

Here is the problem: if I installl MyGem into a new project by adding it into my gemfile like this:

```
gem "mygem", :path => "path/to/my/local/gem"
```

then this new project is not being able to use cancan methods, and I have to explicity declare cancan on the new project gemfile in order to use it.

I tried also using gemspec method, but didn't solve my problem either.
Any ideas?

**Update**

I just wanted to add that when i only have myGem declared in my new application gemfile, after I run `bundle install` all the dependencies are installed.
That is, if i run `gem list` the "cancan" gem is displayed, but I still can't access it methods from the application level.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i've solved this. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it did work.

Making the application level developer to explicity add the dependencies in his gemfile didn't make any sense. So, as the gems did were being installed, i just required all the gem dependencies in my `my_engine.rb` file **inside** my gem.

Following the example, in my `my_engine.rb` I added the following line

`require "cancan"`

And that'it...
Even better you could do:

`autoload :CanCan, "cancan"`

So the module would be loaded only when it is called.
And even better than that, you could load only the file from cancan that you are using (maybe you don't need to load all of it).

You can add that line in you `my_gem.rb` file or your `engine.rb` file if you are using engines.

That worked for me, I hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use add_dependency instead of add_runtime_dependency (this may help with cancan) then run bundle update on your new project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but it didn't work. It raised the same error as if the cancan gem wasn't even installed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "cancan" gem name actually match the name to be require'd?

Example for yajl-ruby gem:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{yajl-ruby}
...
```

But when require'ing the library, you'd use a different string:

```
require 'yajl'
```

That means in your Gemfile, you have to explicitly require the dependency (which you said you wanted to avoid).

```
gem 'yajl-ruby', '>=1.0', :require => 'yajl'
```

To avoid needing to do this, and if you're the author of the "cancan" dependency, you should make the gem name matches the require name.

The only alternative I can think of is require'ing the dependency directly in one of your source files (like you did in your solution).

Comment: "Cancan" was just a gem I took as an example for presenting the problem. The actual real problem consisted in a bunch of gems that weren't being loaded.

So, in that group of gems there were some gems that matched it name with the actual name to be required and some other thar not, but no gem was being loaded.

I had to require them in the source in order to load them.
thanks for the answer!